# Holistic and simplified view for Airflow job status

Tags: airflow, bigdata, monitoring

Sorry if this is a dumb question. I'm still a somewhat novice dev.

I'm interested in creating a holistic view that shows the current status of every airflow job my team maintains. The point would be to simplify the view rather than having the user go into the Airflow UI to check the status. I would be interested in something along the lines of a front-end webpage that has a list of each of the DAGs and kind of a progress bar whose length depends on the number of tasks for each DAG. If a task is currently running, it would be light-green, solid green for success and red for failures. Similar to the Airflow UI but a lot simpler. I would also want the home view to show the current day with a left and right arrow to go through each day if the user is interested. Essentially it would be a airflow monitoring system for less technical users.

What would be a good way to go about this?

I'm also open to any other solutions anyone may have come up that could help with simplify monitoring a large amount of airflow jobs.

Kind of looking for some folks to help me brainstorm. Not sure if Stack is the right place for it. :)

I'll be the developer of this app so no need to pull punches as far as the technical end goes.

Currently, I'm thinking of using a standard web app where the screen will be populated by a log that I'll keep in a backend database that gets populated by a function that gets called whenever a task concludes within a DAG. The view will always show current day and whichever DAGs are scheduled to run during that day with whatever their progress is.

Answer (score 0):

Airflow allows creating [plugins](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/plugins.html) to expose web views with `FlaskAppBuilder`, so you can create a view and add whatever you want in it, then add it to the Airflow UI.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot. I see Flask so it might be the exact thing I'm looking for. :)